# Show that, if $f$ and $g$ are divisible polynomials by the polynomial $h$, then the same occurs with $f + g$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

Good afternoon!

Would it be possible for someone to appreciate my attempt to demonstrate what is being asked for?

I need to show that, if $f$ and $g$ are divisible polynomials by the polynomial $\color{#08f}h$, then the same occurs with $f + g$.

Here is my prove:

Let
\begin{align}
f&= q_1\color{#08f}h \tag{1} \\ \\
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
g &= q_2\color{#08f}h\tag{2} \\ \\
\end{align}
Let $q$ the quotient and $r$ the division remainder of $f+g$ by $\color{#08f}h$, thus
\begin{align}
f+g &= qf +qg + r \tag{3} \\ \\
\end{align}
by performing the appropriate algebraic manipulations, we have:

\begin{gather}
r &=&(f+g)-qf-qg \\ \\
&=& q_1\color{#08f}h+q_2\color{#08f}h-qq_1\color{#08f}h -qq_2\color{#08f}h \\ \\
&=& [(q_1 +q_2) -( q_1+q_2)q]\color{#08f}h 
\end{gather}

This result concludes the demonstration.

Comment: Why so complicated? $f+g = q_1 h + q_2 h = (q_1 + q_2) h$.

Comment: I don't understand what $q$ is in equation $(3)$.  If $f=q_1h$ and $g=q_2h$ then $f+g=(q_1+q_2)h$.

Comment: @saulspatz. For it is necessary to show that $r$ is divisible by $h$.

Comment: If $q$ is the quotient and $r$ the remainder of dividing $f+g$ by $h$ then $f+g = qh + r$. Your equation (3) makes no sense to me.

Comment: Then how come $h$ doesn't appear anywhere in the equation?

Comment: @MartinR. I needed to use the 13 property of the link  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html - Properties (6-8) can be proved simply by defining.

Comment: @MartinR - See the link https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vQbcCAmTh2-6dGnF9QzTNzDnL7CX3DzKj0292s_Au1Wclwbq3nwsqM9QelIv0K1uIJZo5zu_Kd1Y1_c/pub - but it is Portuguese language.

Comment: @FernandoSousa: I don't speak Portuguese, but it seems to me that that document states that the remainder of dividing $f$ by $g$ is divisible by $h$, not that $f+g$ is divisible by $h$.